# How to save mark radio button to my database access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, radio-button

I just want to know how to save selected radio button to my access database such as Male and Female options...Once i mark male the male text will be saved to the database Here is my Running code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Try
        Dim s As Boolean
        If rdbMale.Checked = True Then
            s = True
        ElseIf rdbFemale.Checked = True Then
            s = False
        End If

        Dim fsreader As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim breader As New BinaryReader(fsreader)
        Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.Length) As Byte
        breader.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.Length)
        fsreader.Close()
        strsql = "insert into students (Stdnt_ID, Fname, Lname, Mname, Gender, Dob, Depart, Crse, Major, Sec, Address, Contact_Number, StudentPic) values (@dtaID, @dtaFname, @dtaLname, @dtaMname, @dtaGend, @dtaDob, @dtaDepart, @dtaCrse, @dtaMajor, @dtaSec,@dtaAddress, @dtaCont, @dtafile)"
        cmd.CommandText = strsql
        cmd.Connection = (OleCn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaID", IDtxts.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaFname", nmetxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaLname", lastxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaMname", mitxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaGend", s)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaDob", dttxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaDepart", dpttxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaCrse", crsetxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaMajor", mjortxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaSec", sectxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaAddress", addtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaCont", contxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtafile", imgbuffer)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        MsgBox("Thank You! A New Student is Successfully Registered")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Please Fill up All the required information")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Any Suggestions and answer will be highly appreciated ..I'm just a beginner thank you guys

Comment: ????aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with this code?